# Нужно вывести всю информацию и найти среднее значение зарплаты всех сотрудников

Tags: python, классы

Создайте класс `Employee` с параметрами:

```
name

age

salary
```

- `__init__(self,name, age, salary)`
- `def printData() // Данная функция возвращает все данные работника.`

Создайте 2 класса которые наследуют от класса `Employee`:

```
    1 – Programmer       

    programmingLanguage
```

- `__init__(self,name, age, salary, programmingLanguage)`

Переопределите функцию `printData()` , относительно их параметрам.

2 – DataAnalytics

databaseTool

- `__init__(self,name, age, salary, databaseTool)`

Переопределите функцию `printData()` , относительно их параметрам.

В основном классе вы должны создать несколько объектов класса Programmer, DataAnalytics и добавить их в общий список для Employee.

**Нужно вывести всю информацию и найти среднее значение зарплаты всех сотрудников.**

---

Вот, что сделал я:

1й файл:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.salary = salary

    def print_data(self):
        return "Employee => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary)

class Programmer(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, programmingLanguage):
        super().__init__(name, age, salary)
        self.programmingLanguage = programmingLanguage

    def print_data(self):
        return "Programmer => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary) + " " + self.programmingLanguage


class DataAnalytics(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, databaseTool):
        super().__init__(name, age, salary)
        self.databaseTool = databaseTool

    def print_data(self):
        return "DataAnalytics => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary) + " " + self.databaseTool
```

2ой файл:

```
from employee import Employee, Programmer, DataAnalytics

e1 = Employee('Victor', 29, 200000)
p2 = Programmer('Alexandra', 24, 300000, 'Java')
d3 = DataAnalytics('Ben', 27, 400000, 'SQL')
print(e1.print_data())
print(p2.print_data())
print(d3.print_data())
```

далее не могу понять *как через новую функцию* **Нужно вывести всю информацию и найти среднее значение зарплаты всех сотрудников**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем функцию, принимающую список юзеров и в ней вызываем у каждого юзера `print_data` и подсчитываем среднюю зарплату

Пример:

```
def print_all_data(users):
    for u in users:
        print(u.print_data())

    print()

    salaries = [u.salary for u in users]
    mean_salary = sum(salaries) / len(salaries)
    print(f'Средняя зарплата: {mean_salary}')


e1 = Employee('Victor', 29, 200000)
p2 = Programmer('Alexandra', 24, 300000, 'Java')
d3 = DataAnalytics('Ben', 27, 400000, 'SQL')
users = [e1, p2, d3]
print_all_data(users)
```

Результат:

```
Employee => Victor 29 200000
Programmer => Alexandra 24 300000 Java
DataAnalytics => Ben 27 400000 SQL

Средняя зарплата: 300000.0
```

---

**PS.**

Для большей читаемости кода, можно параметру функции `print_all_data` указать тип, пример:

```
from typing import List


def print_all_data(users: List[Employee]):
    ...
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @DisplayedName, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Не вполне понятно, что здесь требуется:

> В основном классе вы должны создать несколько объектов класса Programmer, DataAnalytics и добавить их в общий список для Employee.

О каком *основном* классе идет речь, и что за *общий список для Employee*. Но похоже, что создать нужно только экземпляры классов Programmer и DataAnalytics, а вот экземпляры Employee не нужно.

И, возможно, подразумевается что-то вроде этого:

```
class Employee:
    employees = []  # 'общий список для Employee'

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.salary = salary
        
    def print_data(self):
        return "Employee => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary)

    @classmethod
    def all_data(cls):
        return '\n'.join(e.print_data() for e in cls.employees)
    
    @classmethod
    def avr_salary(cls):
        return sum(e.salary for e in cls.employees)/len(cls.employees)

class Programmer(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, programmingLanguage):
        super().__init__(name, age, salary)
        self.programmingLanguage = programmingLanguage
        super().employees.append(self)

    def print_data(self):
        return "Programmer => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary) + " " + self.programmingLanguage

class DataAnalytics(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, databaseTool):
        super().__init__(name, age, salary)
        self.databaseTool = databaseTool
        super().employees.append(self)

    def print_data(self):
        return "DataAnalytics => " + self.name + " " + str(self.age) + " " + str(self.salary) + " " + self.databaseTool
```

тогда результат будет такой:

```
p2 = Programmer('Alexandra', 24, 300000, 'Java')
d3 = DataAnalytics('Ben', 27, 400000, 'SQL')

print(Employee.all_data())
'''
Programmer => Alexandra 24 300000 Java
DataAnalytics => Ben 27 400000 SQL
'''
print(Employee.avr_salary())
'''
350000.0
```